# How to use Actions from Notification without starting Activity

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, mediaplayback

So I'm working on a simple music player. The music player as it names states, can play a song, pause playback, forward to next song, go back to previous song, and stop playback completely. When you play a song, there will be a notification displayed with the Artist Name, and the Song Name; this notification also has three buttons (Actions): Stop, Pause an Next.

What I'm having issues with is making sure that when either action is clicked, the playback control related to the Action is triggered, and well, I have absolutely no idea on how to do that. I searched the Android Notification: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html but It does not clarifies, or dedicates too much info on Notification Actions.

Here is a simple action for instance (which should be associated with the "Next" button click on the notification: **Note:** All of the code described below is written under the following package: **com.deadpixels.light.player** and the Activity is called: **PlayerActivity**

```
public void nextSong() {
    if (position == songs.size() -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No more songs on queue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            buttonPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        }
        return;
    }
    else {
        position++;
        playSong(songs.get(position));
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(KEY_NEXT);
PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = createPendingResult(0, nextIntent, 0);
```

Where the action for the NextIntent is:

```
public static final String KEY_NEXT = "com.deadpixels.light.player.PlayerActivity.nextSong";
```

and then I add that to the Notification via addAction():

```
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.not_action_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent);
```

Do you guys know what else I could try? Using what I explained above does nothing at all, the notification shows up, and has three action buttons, but clicking on them does nothing for me.

At one point I thought maybe if I added the intent filters with the action names, but then I thought, well, they are all on the same namespace, why should I?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've solved this problem using broadcasts. For example, to send a broadcast that advances to the next song, you can use the following:

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(KEY_NEXT);
PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);
```

Then, register a `BroadcastReceiver` within your `Activity`:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(KEY_NEXT);
// Add other actions as needed

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(KEY_NEXT)) {
            nextSong();
        } else if (...) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}

registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

If you're using a service to manage background playback, then you'll want to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the service instead of the activity. Be sure to store the `receiver` instance somewhere so that you can unregister it when the activity or service is shut down.

Comment: Be sure to store the receiver instance .. store where?

Comment: @anonymous Keep a reference to it in your activity or service.

Comment: Why don't you register BroadcastReceiver in manifest and make as separate class?

Comment: @streamride You could do that. Sometimes it's useful to have fine-grained control over their lifecycle, though. For example, in the context of this question, you may only want to listen for broadcasts when a specific activity is being used.

Comment: unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver); for lazy people :P

Comment: How to change album art and song title in the notification?